# How to send request in JSON format with JQuery Datatables Editor

Tags: jquery, datatables, jquery-datatables-editor

In Jquery Datatables editor, is there any option by which data with request sent to the server can be wrapped into JSON? Everywhere, the data is being sent as URL Parameters. And there seems to be no option for JSON request.

Thanks.

Comment: _And there seems to be no option for JSON request._...how do you know? Can you post in what terms you mentioned this.

Comment: In all examples given in the website, I searched and found nowhere such an option. Also, I used firebug for those examples, and everywhere the request is being sent in URL parameters format. Thanks

Comment: do you know about type **POST** what is the use of it?

Comment: Yes Sir, Post is a method in which  query strings (name/value pairs) are sent in the HTTP message body of request

Comment: check this out if it helps in understanding what is going on: https://editor.datatables.net/examples/advanced/localstorage.html

Answer (score 4):

try this function in ajax section, works for me.

```
var editor = new $.fn.dataTable.Editor( {
  ajax: {
    url: '...',
    data: function ( d ) {
      return JSON.stringify( d );
    }
  },
  ...
} );
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow.  Code-only answers are discouraged.  Please add some details describing why and how this code works to solve the original question.  By elaborating and providing these useful details, it is more likely to help the original poster understand why instead of just providing the code that may be a solution.  This also helps future visitors to the question understand why it works the way it does.  Please read [How to Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) in the help section.  Thanks for contributing!